# Custom Login Page in Office 365

Tags: office-365, branding, custom, custom-login-page

I need to create a brand new login page for Users for Office 365 SharePoint site

e.g. `https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/Test1` .

After entering correct credentials in custom Login page if the user has access to SharePoint site then user must be redirected to Office 365 site

i.e. `https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/Test1`

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. You need to use the login functionality provided by the platform.